# Can't change magento 2 orders to complete

Tags: magento2

I have captured a payment for orders and created an invoice and a shipment but I don't see the complete option in the order status dropdown which I believe that is where I change the order to complete.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I don't see any errors in the exception log but I can't figure out how to get my orders changed to completed

UPDATE: This is the invoice that I created for this order

[image]

This is the shipment that I created for this order

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Order have total 3 states.

1) Pending

2) Processing

3) Complete

When customer place any order by default its status is **Pending**.

When you **Ship** that order its status is **Processing**

When you **generate INVOICE** of that order its status is automatically **complete.**

After that you can see **COMPLETE** in order admin grid . also when you click on that you will see status in dropdown as **complete**

**You don't need to do it manually.**

> If you complete  all the steps like shippment(processing),
>   invoice(complete) then its automatically shows status as complete.

Comment: I edited my post to show you that I created an invoice for this order and a shipment for this order and as you can see I'm not seeing the complete option in the dropdown

Comment: I have seen your updated Question . Do one thing first using customer login place new order and then go to your admin . first create shipment and check its status its "Processing" after that create invoice and submit it. go to the order again and check its status "Completed". You must need to do shippment before creating invoice. Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes that seems to be the issue. I created the invoices and then the shipments. They should definitely fix this bug. I deleted the invoice and recreated it and it changed to completed

Comment: @user3610374  Good to hear this you have solved the issue . Happy to help keep helping :)

Answer (score 2):

[The accepted answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149747/55289) has all the information that you need.

However, it is important to note that the created shipments and invoices must be in a "final" state themselves for the associated order to be marked as complete. For example, I ran into the issue when I had generated both the shipment and invoice, but I had not captured the payment from the invoice, leading the *invoice's* status to be "pending." This situation prevented the *order's* status from proceeding to "complete."

The images in the question do not capture the invoice/shipment table column containing the objects' status. Below is an example of an invoice status that will cause the order to progress to the "complete" status:

[image: invoice with paid status]

I hope this adds clarification for others who may be confused.

Answer (score 0):

Once customer order is placed then admin can check that order and change the order status

from pending to Complete

**Sales > Orders**

[image: order pending]

click on **view** for a particular order  and Click on **Invoice**

[image: View]

click on **submit Invoice**
[image: submit invoice]

Now Order status changes from **pending** to **complete**
[image: order complete status]